# Checking for ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a 3x3 array of integers (0 or 1): `int[][] matrix`. The goal is to get through the maze (matrix) of 0's and 1's by assuming the 0's are walls. I'm not sure how to go about checking the neighbors.

For example, starting at `[0][0]` and checking above it, I need to do something like:

`if (currentPosition.getColumn()-1 != null && !checkIfWall[getRow()][getColumn()-1]) {
//do stuff
}`

Where checkIfWall is a boolean 2D array of walls or not wall. The problem is that `checkIfWall` returns ArrayOutOfBounds if any of the values are -1. Additionally, I have to write three other if statements to check below, left, and right, which seems tedious. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you allowing `getRow()` and `getColumn()` to return -1 and 0, respectively, to begin with?

Comment: why have an int[] of only 0 and 1's and also have a boolean array that represents the same thing?

Comment: the getRow and getColumn get the current position. I suppose you can have the int[][] matrix just check it's a 1 or a 0 instead of the boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it is assume that any location outside the array is a wall - so then you can create a function to do a collision test and check the bounds inside that.

```
 boolean isWall(int x, int y) {
     if (x<0||x>3)
        return true;
     if (y<0||y>3)
        return true;
     return data[x][y]==0;
 }
```

Now you can just call isWall for any co-ordinates you like and it will never error, and so you don't need to worry about where you are in all your other algorithms - anything outside the maze is always treated as a wall.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you're confusing the directions ... you think about "up" as "-1", but usually what happens in a 2d array is that the top left corner is 0,0. and as "y" grows, it's going "down".

In any case, regarding your question, I would solve this by having a method that simply gets the current location and a direction (up,down, right, left, either strings, or better enums). You should have in your file a global variable for the size, so you can verify you are in a "valid" state, and if you're trying to check a value "outside" the array, it should return false (treat as a wall, since you can't go that way).

This will have the benefits of making your code readable as well. for example: `if (isValid(this, up)) go up...` and so on...